# How do I get rid of this weird search suggestion in the Gmail app?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search, mobile

I was searching the term gift card in the Gmail app, and it suggests this "sexualgoddess@clean-veri.com" for some reason. It must be in my Google history somewhere but I can't find it. Searching for that email address in both my inbox and my web activity shows no results. Where else could that be so that I can delete it?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about mobile apps are off-topic. It might be on-topic in [android.se]